# dmcrypt : What happens when userspace crypto wrapper not present?

Tags: linux, encryption, arm, dm-crypt

I am trying to set up an encrypted volume to store files securely. This is done on a NextThingCo pocketchip, but the OS is based on debian so I guessed I would give it a try here first, as my question is more related to dmcrypt than the platform itself (or so I think).

The recipe that I built so far is the following (may be incorrect or overly complicated):

1. Create a file
2. Set it up as a loop device.
3. Do the crypsetup for formatting and open. "abc" is the password, fed through stdin (is this assumption correct?).
4. Make a filesystem
5. Mount

So it looks like this:

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=./encrypted.volume bs=512K count=200
 sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ./encrypted.volume  
 echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop0
 echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup open /dev/loop0 vault
 sudo mkfs /dev/mapper/vault
 sudo mount /dev/mapper/vault /mnt/vault
```

Now, all this seems to work fine and dandy, that is until I used the --debug parameter (I wanted to try other parameters as well e.g. key-size). And I realized the following messages:

```
# cryptsetup 1.7.0 processing "cryptsetup -v --debug --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 
512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 --timeout 10 --use-random luksFormat /dev/loop0"
# Running command luksFormat.
...
# Userspace crypto wrapper cannot use aes-xts-plain64 (-95).
...
device-mapper: remove ioctl on temporary-cryptsetup-6661 failed: Device or resource busy    <------ appears when I change the  --key-size to 512 i.s.o. default 256
...
device-mapper: remove ioctl on temporary-cryptsetup-6698 failed: Device or resource busy
```

I tried running the benchmark too:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ sudo cryptsetup --debug benchmark
[sudo] password for chip:
# cryptsetup 1.7.0 processing "cryptsetup --debug benchmark"
# Running command benchmark.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.6.4) initialized in cryptsetup library version 1.7.0.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.4.13-ntc-mlc armv7l.
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha1: 59041 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha1        59041 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha256: 79437 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha256      79437 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash sha512: 40705 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-sha512      40705 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash ripemd160: 50412 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-ripemd160   50412 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# KDF pbkdf2, hash whirlpool: 7481 iterations per second (256-bits key).
PBKDF2-whirlpool    7481 iterations per second for 256-bit key
# Cannot initialise cipher aes, mode cbc.
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Command failed with code 95: Operation not supported
```

Here is some additional info about the platform and OS:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ uname -r
4.4.13-ntc-mlc
chip@chip:~/data/run$ cat /boot/config-4.4.13-ntc-mlc | grep CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER
# CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER is not set
```

I understand that I would need to recompile the kernel after I set CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_SKCIPHER so the userspace crypto API becomes available. I don't think there is a way around that, is there?

I LuksDump the information about the storage file:

```
chip@chip:~/data/run$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump ./encrypted.volume

LUKS header information for ./encrypted.volume

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes          <------- ???
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64  <------- ???
Hash spec:      sha256       
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      ee f8 8d ad 9b 67 d9 7d cb 20 fe a9 25 a3 8b a5 c2 65 56 dd
MK salt:        38 74 e8 9d 77 6a 93 b5 03 41 cb 3e ce 79 b4 00
                55 f3 98 8f c5 a7 14 05 25 9c 4e 91 68 1a 53 37
MK iterations:  18500
UUID:           36912ea4-9adb-4d1f-b9f2-f6a09a258833

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             150587
        Salt:                   e8 4f f3 c1 07 1a 2b 2d d2 d9 f4 55 0f b3 13 28
                                2a 69 06 aa a0 94 4a 05 5d 5f e9 28 9b 91 39 94
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

However, I have a few questions about the current situation:

- Is the partition actually encrypted? If so, with which scheme?

  - How to check this on the command line? Trying to dump information about the partition tells me that "there is a LUKS header", but that does not tell me whether the data is encrypted or not.
- How to solve the ''resource busy'' situation, which would let me use a key size of 512?

Thank you for reading all the way here. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT (08/12/17):
- Last lines of 
`crypsetup --help`:

```
<name> is the device to create under /dev/mapper
<device> is the encrypted device
<key slot> is the LUKS key slot number to modify
<key file> optional key file for the new key for luksAddKey action

Default compiled-in key and passphrase parameters:
        Maximum keyfile size: 8192kB, Maximum interactive passphrase length 512 (characters)
Default PBKDF2 iteration time for LUKS: 2000 (ms)

Default compiled-in device cipher parameters:
        loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
        plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits, Password hashing: ripemd160
        LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits, LUKS header hashing: sha256, RNG: /dev/urandom
```

- output of /proc/crypto:
  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dc9fd345e631fd9fc59c88120c6f8a5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your kernel doesn't support 512-bit keys with aes-xts-plain64, and doesn't do aes mode cbc at all:

```
# Cannot initialise cipher aes, mode cbc.
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Command failed with code 95: Operation not supported
```

but that just stops the benchmark, xts is preferred over cbc anyway. I think you could get more modes available by rebuilding/getting a new kernel (or maybe modprobeing, I'm not 100% sure).

There's a little conflicting info about aes with 512-bit keys, this Q on crypto.SE says [Why we can't implement AES 512 key size?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20253/why-we-cant-implement-aes-512-key-size) and concludes it's just not defined/supported, but using `--cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512` works fine for my cryptsetup (v1.7.3) and my /proc/crypto has an xts(aes) entry supporting keysizes 32-64 bytes.

- Anyway, from luksDump the `./encrypted.volume` file looks encrypted with aes in mode xts-plain64 (aes-xts-plain64). At least anything written to it would be encrypted, it'll be untouched if you haven't luksOpen-ed and written to it.
- `./encrypted.volume` is not a separate disk partition, it's just a file/container.
- You'll use up lots of your entropy using `dd` to take 100M (512*200?) out of /dev/urandom, and it's unnecessary. Creating the container file using zeros is fine (or just `fallocate`). Once it's luksFormatted *then* you fill it with zeros which will get encrypted & written to disk.

  - See the setup section of https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions
- What's the last 10 lines or so of `cryptsetup --help`? It'll say what the defaults are.
- What's in `/proc/crypto`? It'll show you the available encryption methods.
- Also recent cryptsetup's handle loop files themselves, so you can skip losetup and let cryptsetup handle it.
- If your shell saves the history, your passphrase ("abc") could be stored in plaintext, that's not great. It might be visible from `ps` too, if it lists full command lines. Using another way to get the passphrase to stdin may be safer, or use a keyfile on a secure medium (external USB/device) or in ramfs, etc. See 2.14 in the FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll add the information on my original post.

With your first bullet:
`Anyway, from luksDump the ./encrypted.volume file looks encrypted with aes in mode xts-plain64 (aes-xts-plain64). At least anything written to it would be encrypted, it'll be untouched if you haven't luksOpen-ed and written to it.`

Do you mean that  encrypted.volume is actually encrypted, despite the lack of userspace API? I'm concerned that the Luks header says one thing, but the access to the data is doing something else; e.g. plaintext r/w

Comment: After reading the links, I changed the recipe as follows:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=quick.volume bs=512K count=100
sudo losetup -f
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 quick.volume
echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup --debug luksFormat /dev/loop0
echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup --debug open /dev/loop0 quick
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/quick
echo "abc" | sudo cryptsetup --debug close quick
hexdump quick.volume`

Reading the hexdump, I see garbled data after 2MB. So I think it is actually encrypted but with which cipher? Should I believe luksDump, saying xts-plain64, even without userspace API?

Comment: 2MB is usually the size of the LUKS header, and the encrypted data starts after, so the garbled data sounds like it's encrypted OK. I'd believe cryptsetup's luksDump, or while it's opened you could check `dmsetup` too, it will even show the actual encryption key ([fyi could add a new passphrase *without* knowing an existing one](https://superuser.com/questions/1277948/how-to-find-my-luks-encryption-passphrase-inside-decrypted-filesystem/1278023#1278023)). Looks like the [kernel's crypto API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/crypto/index.html) works fine, cryptsetup's ok, just no aes-cbc

Comment: Finally, I used `dmsetup` to verify the encrypted file. The result was the following:  

`chip@chip:~$ sudo dmsetup table --showkeys /dev/mapper/quick
0 98304 crypt aes-xts-plain64 <32BYTENUMBER> 0 7:0 4096`

I am now more confident that my information is encrypted. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Welcome :) I had another idea, you could create a small LUKS container on another computer, and see if it's read & written to on this system, then bring it back to the other computer & check the new info, or vice-versa.