# How to find my LUKS encryption passphrase inside decrypted filesystem?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, passwords, luks

I have lost my encryption passphrase, however my computer is still on and I would like to know if there's a way to see my passphrase to avoid having to backup my data and reinstall.
The hard drive was encrypted by Ubuntu's installer.

Comment: You can't see the passphrase, but apparently you can change it -  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161915/change-password-on-a-luks-filesystem-without-knowing-the-password#161920

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a new key, if the device is still open / "decrypted". Basically, if the device is `/dev/sdb2` and it's mapped name is `map_name`:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdb2 --master-key-file <(dmsetup table --showkeys map_name | awk '{ print $5 }' | xxd -r -p)
```

It takes the master key currently used & provided by `dmsetup`, separates the key with `awk` (`cut` would work too), reverses the hexdump, and adds a new key with it. Like cryptsetup's man page says about the `--master-key-file` option: *"For luksAddKey this allows adding a new passphrase without having to know an  exiting one."*

FYI, the `xxd` command is in the `vim-common` package on Debian / Ubuntu, there's an `xxd` package but it's not available for oldstable & older Ubuntus.

<sub>From the [linked Q on unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161915/change-password-on-a-luks-filesystem-without-knowing-the-password#161920) (thanks davidgo).</sub>